# Request body is empty when posting a postman form-data

Tags: node.js, postman, form-data

I spend the whole day trying to figure out the solution for this problem, but I didn't. So I am asking you please for Help.

I sent a request with postman using the POST method in a form-data type and I consoled the req.body in vscode, the console shows the object that it was sent from postman, it contain the data correctly, no bugs.

```
   router.post("/addPost/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.send("success");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Then I repeated the same parameters and the same steps but using PUT method and I consoled the req.body in vscode but here the console shows an empty object of req.body.

```
   router.put("/edit/:id", async (req, res) => {
try {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("success");
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}});

module.exports = router;
```

the main.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const URI = process.env.URI;
mongoose
.connect(URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
})
.then(() => console.log("Connected to DB"))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
app.use("/api/user", require("./routes/user/user"));
app.use("/api/admin", require("./routes/admin/admin"));
app.listen(5000, () => console.log(`server up and running`));
```

Plesae help me.

Comment: If you can share code snippet, it'll be easier to answer the question sooner. Without the code, I can think of two possible scenarios here. 1) Did you use bodyparser in your code? 2) Since it is a PUT request, having no content-length header may  indicate absence of request body.

Comment: Can you share the main.js as well?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a put request that is not supported by default make it a POST request and add `_method => 'PUT'` along with the data you are passing

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because form-data doesn't work well with PUT request. Traditionally, form-data only work with GET and POST requests.
You can make work-arounds to make it work in PUT request.

1. Add Content-Type and Content-Length headers to indicate there is a request body.
2. Use a bodyParser middleware.

It is better to use POST request whenever there is a need to handle form-data.

Comment: same problem with POST in that route too, I really can't understand why, It used t work correctly with my other codes!